# how to relate to a relative css of master page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have few html pages which are generated by my java application:

```
html_pages/
   |
   ----> landin_page.html

html_pages/details
   |
   ----> index1.html

html_pages/more_details
   |
   ----> index2.html

html_pages/css
   |
   ----> master_page.css
```

I want to reference the master_page.css in the header of each html page.

how can i relate to it?

I thought to do it using absolute path, but I get 404

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/html_pages/css/master_page.css">
```

Comment: File is named `master_page.css`, not `delta_samples.css`. Also `/html_pages/css/delta_samples.css` appears to be relative path, not absolute path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **${pageContext.request.contextPath}** is the standard way to mention the full path.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/delta_samples.css">
```

Adding **${pageContext.request.contextPath}** does the trick.

Adding "../" also works but is not recommended as best practices !! And code might break at times if this is used.

Comment: but as i show in the structure - they are in different folders

Comment: using pageContext will bring the file from wherever it is located..try the below

href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html_pages/css/delta_samples.css"

Comment: ${pageContext.request.contextPath} is jquery?

Comment: I get an error:
`http://mydomanin.com/722/201609181256/${pageContext.request.contextPath}/html_pages/css/master_page.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: ${pageContext.request.‌​contextPath} is the root path - if your root path is already there then just use href="master_page.css"

Comment: i don't think it's already there - how can i tell? in addition why do i get the 404 error then?

Comment: 404 means file not found error !! the requested file is not found at the specified path !! Everything is trial & error ... No one is a born master :P try it out yourself - though it takes some patience :)

Comment: i tried several ways including `/html_pages/css/master_page.css` which all gave 404 , that's why i came with that q to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following to the `<head>` of each of your pages (assuming they are in the same directory as the CSS file), it should use the stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master_page.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: but as i show in the structure - they are in different folders

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `..` to indicate the parent directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/delta_samples.css">
```

Comment: No file named `delta_samples.css` appears at Question?

Comment: but as i show in the structure - they are in different folders (landing_page and index1 for example)

Comment: Try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/master_page.css">` for landin_page.html